# How do I do Promise chaining in this ES6 JS code

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I just got my interview results back from a company called [Canva](http://www.canva.com). One of the feedback was that I was supposed to use Promise chaining in the following code. I am unable to comprehend how to do any chaining when there is only one Promise involved ( `aTeam.setTeam()` returns a Promise)

```
getTeam(teamId){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // we first scan to see if the team has been initialized already. if so, we resolve immediately
        if(this.teams[teamId]) return resolve(this.teams[teamId]);
        // if not, we create a new Team, cache it, and issue a request to the server to set it
        let aTeam = new Team(this,teamId); this.teams[teamId] = aTeam;
        aTeam.setTeam().then(()=>resolve(aTeam)).catch((err)=>reject(err));
    })
}
```

Please advise me how would I do Promise chaining here.

My complete code is at [Canva's Tournament Challenge interview question](https://github.com/anandamarsh/Canva).

Comment: Read: [Promise chaining](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining)

Comment: No, you're not supposed to do promise chaining here. You just should avoid using the `new Promise` constructor.

Comment: What does the `setTeam` promise resolve with?

Comment: setTeam returns a new Promise()

Comment: setTeam returns a new Promise() and it resolves to nothing, I mean, it just goes resolve(). Team is a class, and setTeam() is supposed to make an asynch call and set itself up after it has been instantiated. Thanks to yours and MinusFour's answers, I understand what is wrong (I doubt the assessor had meant this though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, it seems you are wrapping your promises, which I take is what they mean by "chaining".

You do:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject){
    someOtherPromise.then(r => resolve(r), err => reject(err));
});
```

You don't need to wrap them, just return the promise:

```
return someOtherPromise;
```

For example, your `getTeam` function could simply be:

```
getTeam(){
    if(this.teams[teamId]){
       return Promise.resolve(this.teams[teamId]);
    }
    let aTeam = new Team(this,teamId);
    this.teams[teamId] = aTeam;
    return aTeam.setTeam();
}
```

Comment: Aah thanks, I understand it now. setTeam() should return a Promise that would resolve to 'this' , ie the object which has been configured as a result of the asynch call that setTeam() makes. This has nothing to do with Promise chaining though. Its more like the situation try{} catch(err) {throw new Error(err)} . Thanks for clarifying.